# How does protobuf parse enums from strings?

Tags: enums, protocol-buffers

Given a proto definition like:

```
enum Foo {
    STUFF = 1;
    A_THING = 2;
}
```

...will protobuf parse any of the following strings into values correctly?

- STUFF
- Stuff
- stuff
- AThing
- aThing
- A_THING

Furthermore, does the parser implementation differ by language?

(The parser function in C++ would be named `Foo_Parse(const std::string&, Foo*)`; not sure what it would be in other languages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enum name-parsing helper for your `Foo` would only accept the *exact* strings "STUFF" and "A_THING".

Note that this name-parsing helper is just a convenience function for you. This is not a core Protobuf feature. In particular, enum names are *not* sent on the wire using the standard Protobuf encoding. It's important to make this clear since when talking about "parsing" it's easy to mistake this as having to do with Protobuf wire-format parsing, which it does not.

Since this is just a random helper and not a core feature, implementations in other languages could in theory offer helpers implementing arbitrary logic. You need to check the documentation for the specific language. However, I would be somewhat surprised if any language implemented an enum name-parsing helper that accepted different strings from the C++ one.